# Exhaust temperature after regeneration in a combined Brayton-Rankine cycle with regeneration added to the Brayton portion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

So consider a combined Brayton-Rankine cycle that has regeneration in the Brayton portion of the cycle. The Brayton compressor and turbine both have isentropic efficiencies as well as the Rankine turbine.

The process goes as follows:

Points 1-2: air goes through compressor

2-3: heat added by means of regenerator

3-4: heat added by means of combustor

4-5: air goes through turbine

5-6: heat rejected (regenerator)

6-7: exhaust goes through heat exchanger connected to steam cycle and leaves via exhaust pipe

8-9: water goes through pump in steam cycle

9-10: heat added by means of heat exchanger from 6-7

10-11: steam turbine

11-8: steam goes through condenser

Here is everything that is known:

mass flow rate of the gas cycle

(gas cycle) the temperatures at all the necessary points to find the net work and heat going into the system (Temperatures at the following points: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)

(steam cycle) enthalpies needed to determine the heat rejected and the the work from the pump and turbine (Enthalpies at all stages of the steam cycle: 8, 9, 10, 11)

temperature of the exhaust after going through the steam cycle heat exchanger

the average constant pressure specific heat of air

To find the total net work of both cycles, the mass flow rate of the steam cycle is needed. To find this, the temperature of the exhaust after going through the regenerator, but before going through the steam cycle heat exchanger, is also needed.

I don't know how to find that exhaust temperature.

Comment: And the diagram would be a good step.

Comment: See http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~kadem/Brayton%20cycle%20with%20regeneration.pdf

Comment: I am sure this is a school exercise, but I'm curious why any real process would use this, rather than a direct Rankine or Direct Brayton cycle.